CustomTkinter how to set length of textbox
I am working on a GUI using Customtkinter where I will have multiple inputs in textboxes, using .place() I got my textbox displaying where I wanted it inside of the frame.
However I want the textbox to be longer-
I tried to use .pack(ipadx=90, ipady=10) which are the dimensions I was after, but if I implement this the position of the textbox changes- I seem to only be able to use either .pack() or .place(), however if I use just .pack() I can't get my desired location and if I use just .place() then I can't have my desired textbox size.
class root(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.title("GenSoft")
        self.geometry("800x480")
        self.resizable()
        self.state("normal")
        self.iconbitmap()

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

    
        self.tabview = ctk.CTkTabview(self,
                             width=800,
                             height=480,
                             corner_radius=20,
                             fg_color="#ffffff",
                             segmented_button_selected_color="red",
                             segmented_button_fg_color="black",
                             segmented_button_selected_hover_color="green",
                             segmented_button_unselected_hover_color="green")
        self.tabview.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        self.tabview.add("Home")
        self.tabview.add("New Recipe")
        self.tabview.add("Saved Recipe")
        self.tabview.tab("Home").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure grid of individual tabs
        self.tabview.tab("New Recipe").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tabview.tab("Saved Recipe").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), text="Ingredient", text_color="#9933cc", anchor="w", justify="left", font=("Arial Bold", 16)).place(x=25, y=65)
        self.label2 = ctk.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), text="Int", text_color="#9933cc", anchor="w", justify="center", font=("Arial Bold", 16)).place(x=200, y=65)
        self.label3 = ctk.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), text="Unit", text_color="#9933cc", anchor="w", justify="center", font=("Arial Bold", 16)).place(x=375, y=65)
        self.ingredientEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"),placeholder_text="ingredient")
        self.ingredientEntry.pack(ipadx=90, ipady=10)
        self.ingredientEntry.place(x=25, y=100)
        self.ingredientEntries = []
        self.addButton = ctk.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), text="Add Ingredient", command=self.add_ingredient)
        self.addButton.place(x=25, y=25)
        self.saveButton = ctk.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), text="Save Recipe", command=self.save_recipe)
        self.saveButton.place(x=175, y=25)
    def add_ingredient(self):
        newEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), placeholder_text="ingredient")
        newEntry.place(x=25, y =150)
        self.ingredientEntries.append(newEntry) # Add the new entry to your list

What would be my best solution for this- is there a solution with .place() rather than .pack() as I find .pack() is a lot more difficult to get elements in desired positions.
Also as a secondary issue- my add_ingredient function is supposed to add new textbox fields when the addButton is pressed, but when I use .place() I can only set the location of the first textbox generated, how would I get the subsequent textboxes to appear a set distance below the first?
Note I tagged TKinter as a lot of solutions for TKinter are transferable into Customtkinter- so if you have a solution using TKinter I may be able to convert it across.
Many Thanks! C0untV

You can set the width option of CTkEntry to adjust the width of the entry box.
To place the new entry box below the last one, you can use the y position and height of the last entry box to place the new one.
class root(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.ingredientEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"),
                                            placeholder_text="ingredient",
                                            width=160) # set the width to whatever you want
        #self.ingredientEntry.pack(ipadx=90, ipady=10) # don't need to call this
        self.ingredientEntry.place(x=25, y=100)
        self.ingredientEntries = [self.ingredientEntry] # save the first entry box
        ...

    def add_ingredient(self):
        # get y position of last entry box
        y = int(self.ingredientEntries[-1].place_info()["y"])
        # get size of last entry box
        w = self.ingredientEntries[-1].winfo_width()
        h = self.ingredientEntries[-1].winfo_height()
        # create new entry box with same width of the one
        newEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("New Recipe"), 
                                placeholder_text="ingredient",
                                width=w)
        # place the new entry box below the last one
        newEntry.place(x=25, y=y+h+5) # change 5 to whatever you want
        self.ingredientEntries.append(newEntry) # Add the new entry to your list

Edit: added screenshot:


I am getting marginal success with this solution- it does give me an extra textbox- but now it stops at 3 rather than the previous 2

I don't have such issue.  Please make sure you have applied all the changes.

You are correct! I was causing issues elsewhere in my code- I had made additions after posting my question here but I have resolved and your solution does work! I was trying to duplicate a column of checkboxes as well but I must have made an error somewhere! Many Thanks for your solution!
